# How to read content body in windows iot

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-iot-core-10

I have a Raspberry Pi3 with windows Iot installed.

I have written a background app in c# to handle rest api calls from my desktop application.

I can certainly invoke my server api calls.

The issue I have is that I am trying to read the content of the body from my client call.

I am posting JSON.

This is my client call:

```
public static async Task<Address> RelayGetCustomerAddress< T >(
    string uriController,
    T jsonObject)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = Uri;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var jsonInput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);
        var contentPost = new StringContent(jsonInput, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = client.PostAsync(uriController, contentPost).Result;
        var data = response;
        data.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var json = await data.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Address>(json);
    }
}
```

This is my code on the Raspberry Pi.
The 1st bit deals with the header which I parse with no problem:

```
var client = new List<string>();
var header2 = new StringBuilder();

using (var input = args.Socket.InputStream)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[BufferSize];
    IBuffer buffer = data.AsBuffer();
    uint dataRead = BufferSize;
    while (dataRead == BufferSize)
    {
        await input.ReadAsync(buffer, BufferSize, InputStreamOptions.Partial);
        header2.AppendLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, data.Length));
        dataRead = buffer.Length;
    }

var requestLines = header2.ToString().Split(new[] { "\n", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var api = requestLines[0].Split(' ')[1].Split('/');
client.Add(api[2]); //controller
client.Add(api[3]);//action
```

This bit gets the the content length:

```
var contentLength2 = requestLines.FirstOrDefault(d => d.StartsWith("Content-Length:", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
uint contentLength = 0;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentLength2))
{
    contentLength = (uint)int.Parse(Regex.Match((contentLength2), @"\d+").Value);
}
```

and finally this bit attempts to read in the body content:

```
if ( contentLength > 0 )
{
    dataRead = BufferSize;
    while ( dataRead == BufferSize )
    {
        await input.ReadAsync( buffer, BufferSize, InputStreamOptions.Partial );
        var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString( data, 0, ( int ) contentLength );
        client.Add( content );
        dataRead = buffer.Length;
    }
}
else
{
    LogVerbose( "Empty JSON Body" );
    client.Add( string.Empty );
}
}
```

I call this api twice.

The 1st time i can get the body content and the 2nd time  it just hangs on:

```
await input.ReadAsync( buffer, BufferSize, InputStreamOptions.Partial
```

Comment: This doesn't look right: `dataRead = 0; while ( dataRead == BufferSize )` - that loop never starts.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError thanks. I have been trying lots of different things, Then me correct my code and report back :)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError thanks I have corrected my code but now I get a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided, it seems that when the 1st bit deals with the header ,the all data of `InputStream` would be read because the `BufferSize` is bigger then the content size, in fact `header2` in your code is full request content. So when you attempted to read in the body content in the final `ReadAsync`, it could not read any data, and it would be blocked to timeout.

You can refer to [IotWeb](https://github.com/sensaura-public/iotweb) or other repo in GitHub. IotWeb provides a simple HTTP server with WebSocket support.